# "Get an idea on/of something"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

In general, is it better to say get an idea *on* or get an idea *of* something?

Here are some examples:

> In order to get an idea on how to build this house...
>
> In order to get an idea of how to build this house...

In my opinion, the first example sounds better. Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 5):

In English, one has an idea *of*... (as well as other prepositions)

> In order to get an idea of how to build this house, I spoke to several architects.

We may think *on* a matter.

> The more I thought on the matter, the more convinced I became that I had been wrong all along.

Comment: The Google search for "to get an idea on" gives 6'030'000 results. Are they all wrong or you can use it depending on the context?

Comment: @aeqr You can't treat Google's result estimates as evidence of standard English usage.  [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) has 268 results for `get an idea of`, but only 1 result for `get an idea on`, and I think this is probably a better indication of standard English usage.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would say that I get ideas *about* things, not *on* or *of* things.

Example:

> I had a good idea *about* how to answer this question, but I wrote this instead.

Answer (score 1):

> ...get an idea on **how to build**...
>
> ...get an idea of **building**...

Use *of* before a verb + -ing.

Comment: That is how I would say it as well, but can you provide a source for this rule?

Comment: _About_ would generally be the best preposition to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

> In order to get an idea **for** building this house...

Comment: Why do you suggest this alternative?

Comment: I think it is more natural than any of the above answers.